# Excel formula to return earliest date in a range & ignores blank cells

Tags: excel

I was able to use the MIN function to return earliest date in a range, but I also found that it returns a default excel date (12/30/1899) when the range of cells are empty.  Is there another way to avoid the default date for blank cells and return blank?

For example:
Range 1 
7/1/2014
7/2/2014
6/30/2014

Result = 6/30/2014

Range 2 (cells are blank because they're still waiting for input)
...
...
...

Result = 12/30/1899

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
=If(Min(A:A) > 0, Min(A:A), "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another formula approach would be to use `SMALL` rather than `MIN` - SMALL will return an error if there are no dates in the range (rather than zero) so you can clean the error up with `IFERROR`, e.g.

`=IFERROR(SMALL(A1:A100,1),"")`

....or you can retain your current formula with a simple MIN and just custom format the result field so that zeroes don't display, e.g. custom format as

`mm/dd/yyyy;;`

Note the two semi-colons - those must be included

Comment: +1 I think all he really needs is the proper format. Although while your code is shorter, i'd love to get some performance testing on the two, as your will index the entire range then go through the index and extract the value passed, in this case the 1st smallest, I would think the `Min` would be much faster, but idk if 2 mins are faster than 1 small. I also don't know about if vs iferror, it is an interesting test.